# How to count all the outlier values in a row?

Tags: r, dataframe

In R (I'm so new) I'm trying to create a `outlier_count` variable where an integer would indicate the number of outlier values per row.

So, let's say my dataset looks like this, and assuming "10" is an outlier:

```
    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
a      1    1   10   10    1    1    1
b     10    1    1    1    1    1    1
c      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
d      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
e      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
f      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I want to end up with something like:

```
    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 outlier_count
a      1    1   10   10    1    1    1             2
b     10    1    1    1    1    1    1             1
c      1    1    1    1    1    1    1             0
d      1    1    1    1    1    1    1             0
e      1    1    1    1    1    1    1             0
f      1    1    1    1    1    1    1             0
```

So, in every row, I know how many values were outliers.

I tried a couple of functions but the variable ends up being `NA` when a single column is `NA`.

Is there an easy, error-proof way of doing this?

Comment: If you could provide a minimal data set for `df$var1`, so that the problem could be reproduced, then it would be easier to catch the problem.

Comment: Those are not `"values per row"`, outliers or not, `df$var1` is a column.

Comment: hi! thank you both.

@Heikki I guess you could use any dataset you wanted, such as `iris[sample(nrow(iris), 10), ]` (using only numerical variables, of course).




@RuiBarradas yes, I'm trying to know if the `df$var1` value is an outlier for a specific row, and add its value to the `outlier_count` variable for the very same row.

Comment: Data sample `iris[sample(nrow(iris), 10), ]` has no NAs.

Comment: @Heikki true, it's easy to insert some NA values but you could also use airquality: `summary(airquality)`, Ozone and Solar.R have NA values.

Comment: The result of this would be one value for every row. There is no rowwise operation here.

Comment: @Parfait hmm why not? I just want, for every row, to check in every column if its value is an outlier. In that case, increase by 1 the `outlier_count` variable. Maybe there's an easier way to do that.

Comment: You are counting outliers across every row in multiple columns. See @RuiBarradas comment above.

Comment: I don't think I get you, I'm so newbie at R. I want, for every row, to have the quantity of values in the very same row that are outliers to its own column. I might remove my code since it's obviously not working well and might be distorting my request.

Comment: I updated my question with some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your explanations in the comments and the edit with the expected output, it becomes very simple.
First read in the data.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
a      1    1   10   10    1    1    1
b     10    1    1    1    1    1    1
c      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
d      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
e      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
f      1    1    1    1    1    1    1
", header = TRUE)
```

Now the code. I will consider an *outlier* everything below or above the `0.05` and `0.95` quantiles. Change this if you want so.

```
out <- sapply(df, function(x) x < quantile(x, 0.05) | x > quantile(x, 0.95))
df$outlier_count <- rowSums(out)
df
```

Note that you can do without explicitly creating the intermediate variable `out`. And make a one-liner out of the code above. That's up to you. I prefer it to have readable code.

Comment: Thanks! I added `na.rm=TRUE` to avoid errors when evaluating NA values.

How can I then specify which columns should be evaluated? Let's say I don't want to include `var7` in the total.

Comment: @afontcu You can do `sapply(df[, 1:6], ...)` or `sapply(df[, -7], ...)`. In the first case you say to which columns you want to apply the function, in the second case to which columns you do *not* want to apply the function.

Comment: I ended up using `subset`. Thank you very much! Works like a charm. Thank you for your patience.